# Why does Mypy report a subset of JSON as invalid?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a base class that returns a JSON type. I then have subclasses that return more specific types that should I think be valid JSON types, but Mypy reports an error:

```
error: Return type "List[Dict[str, JSON]]" of "return_json" incompatible with return type "JSON" in supertype "JsonReturner"  [override]
```

Have I misunderstood something or am I exploring the limits of the type-checking implementation?

Full example:

```
from typing import TypeAlias


JSON: TypeAlias = dict[str, "JSON"] | list["JSON"] | str | int | float | bool | None


class JsonReturner:

    def return_json(self) -> JSON:
        raise NotImplementedError("abstract base class")


class ListJsonReturner(JsonReturner):

    def return_json(self) -> list[JSON]:
        return []


class DictJsonReturner(JsonReturner):

    def return_json(self) -> dict[str, JSON]:
        return {}


class ListDictJsonReturner(JsonReturner):

    def return_json(self) -> list[dict[str, JSON]]:
        return []


class DictListJsonReturner(JsonReturner):

    def return_json(self) -> dict[str, list[JSON]]:
        return {}
```

```
$ mypy jsontypes.py
jsontypes.py:27: error: Return type "List[Dict[str, JSON]]" of "return_json" incompatible with return type "JSON" in supertype "JsonReturner"  [override]
jsontypes.py:33: error: Return type "Dict[str, List[JSON]]" of "return_json" incompatible with return type "JSON" in supertype "JsonReturner"  [override]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all has to do with variance. Read [PEP-483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483) for more information.

Generic types like `list` are *invariant*: a type `list[T]` is not a subtype nor a supertype of `list[U]` unless `T` and `U` are the same type.

Similarly, `dict` is invariant because a two concrete dict types are the same only if their key and value types are the same.

Function types are *covariant* in their return type. For a fixed argument type, `Callable[..., R1]` is a subtype of Callable[..., R2]`when`R1`is a subtype of`R2`.

Each component of a union type is a subtype of the union.

When you override a function, the type of the override must be a subtype of the parent function. As long as you don't change the parameter types, this means the new return type must be a subtype of the original's return type.

In your first two overrides, the return types are subtypes of JSON.

In the last two, they are not. `list[dict[str, JSON]]` is not a subtype of `JSON` because lists are invariant. `dict[str, list[JSON]]` is not a subtype of `JSON` because dicts are invariant.

Comment: Aha. I knew this distinction but I didn't understand it fully. And in fact if I replace dict with Mapping and list with Sequence all is well.

Comment: Ah, right. Variance is only an issue here for *mutable* types, and `Mapping` and `Sequence` imply immutability.